# Google's "Saved Games" and Adobe Air

Tags: android, air, google-play-games, flash-cc

I've recently discovered "Saved Games" (https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames) and I would love to use it to save the state of my game so my users can play on different devices. 
But, I don't know how to do it (I'm using Air and I didn't find any ANE for it).

Right now my saving system works like this: 
user win a game -> game updates the corresponding variable -> game write that variable as the value of an Object (i.e. score.value = wonGames).

When the user restarts the game, the game reads the values of the Object and updates the state of the game. 
It works fine.

But if the user changes his device or want to log in from somewhere else (i'm using Google Play Games Services ANE from Milkman), he has to start anew.

So, "Saved Games" would me to upload the Object to Google Drive.

Do you guys know a way to do that? (or an alternative that doesn't require a server)

Thank you.